# How do I pass values into a map?

Tags: java, dictionary, automation

I have a method that I'm trying to pass values into. The method is:

```
public void createReport(String reportName, Map<String, String> reportParameters){
//code with stuff to execute
}
```

I'm trying to call createReport() from another file and pass the parameters into it, but I'm not able to figure it out. I've tried something like this, but it's not correct:

```
createReport("Summary", "Title", "Test Report", "Author", "Test User", "Color", Green");
```

I'm able to pass in the reportName value of "Summary", but I don't know how to pass in the Map values for reportParameters properly.
I should have a single string value of "Summary" for the reportName value, and then reportParameters should be these pairs:

```
Title = Test Report
Author = Test User
Color = Green
```

How do I pass the Map parameter values into this method correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to call `createReport`, you have 3 options:

### `Map.of`

```
createReport("Summary", Map.of("Title", "Test Report", ....));
```

There is a limit to how many args you can pile in there, but it's quite a few.

### `ImmutableMap.builder`

This requires adding the guava dependency to your project:

```
ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
   .put("title", "Test Report")
   .build()
```

and you can make that as long as it needs to be.

### Ye olde just make a map

```
var map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Title", "Test Report");
.... more put statements
createReport("Summary", map);
```

### A closing note

This is very unjavalike. You don't represent an object with a bunch of strings. You represent them with a definition. This would be far superior:

```
import lombok.*;

@Value @Builder
class Report {
    String name;
    String title;
    @Singular List<String> authors;
    Color color;
}
```

NB: Uses [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)

Comment: Ok, I was able to use Map.of to add the values. Worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a map, not a bunch of Strings.

```
String par1 = ...
Map<String, String> par2 = ...
...
createReport(par1, par2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass values to a map you need to *create* a map. Since map is an interface you need to instantiate a class that implements it. I'll use HashMap for an example (keep in mind HashMap is a class not an interface which is the point).
So:
`Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();`
Seems like Generics might be worth looking into for you as it looks like that is what's causing confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 9 you can use the [static factory mathod](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#immutable) `Map.of()`

```
createReport("Summary", Map.of("Title", "Test Report", "Author", "Test User", "Color", " Green"));
```

If you are using Java 8 you have to construct a Map instance before calling the method

```
Map<String, String> reportParameters = new HashMap<>();
reportParameters.put("Test Report", "Author");
reportParameters.put("Author", "Test User");
reportParameters.put("Color", " Green");

createReport("Summary", reportParameters);
```